# Depth of the SHA-256 collision search knowing partial input and final hashes

Tags: collision-resistance, sha-256

So I have a partial input data (string) `PART1+UNKNOWN+PART2`, length of `UNKNOWN` is self-describing.
I have a bunch of valid hashes (about 8 or so) that are compatible.

My question is then: will bruteforce search for full collision given the data at hand be [as long](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65068905/11541740)?

Comment: Are you really asking for the collisions or finding the pre-images so that once can find the unknown part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but please note that the question/answers you are pointing to are about partial collisions on the output, not partial input. Finding a full hash collision is not computationally feasible for hash functions that are considered secure, such as SHA-256.